# Can anyone remove error from my java program? | Tool: VS Code | error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: myjavacode.Base

Tags: java, inheritance

```
package myjavacode;

// using vs code to run program

class Base{                            

   int x;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        System.out.println("I am in base setting x now");
        this.x = x;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{}


public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World");

        Derived obj = new Derived();
        obj.setX(4);
        System.out.println(obj.getX());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no main method in Base. Only MyClass has main.

Comment: Not enough research effort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Java main method is the entry point of any java program. so you can not run any class without this entry point, it seems you are trying to run the code from the Base class which do not have this main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```